# When are embeddings into Euclidean space unique up to ambient isometry?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Suppose I have a Riemannian smooth manifold $M$ and a smooth isometric embedding $M \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$.  Is this embedding necessarily unique up to some isometry of $\mathbb{R}^n$?  If not, is it possible to insert some extra conditions or structure to make this happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get you started searching, this is known as a *rigidity result* for the isometric embedding problem.

For surfaces in $\mathbb R^3$ there are some well-known results: Leibmann's theorem gives rigidity for the sphere, and Cohn-Vossen
for strictly convex surfaces (i.e. closed surfaces with nonvanishing Gaussian curvature).

The bendability of cylinders rule out a lot of optimistic conjectures. Even for compact surfaces nasty things can happen in general:

[image]

(Image pinched from the book of Montriel & Ros via [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/224711/all-compact-surfaces-s-subseteq-mathbbr3-are-rigid/224733))

For hypersurfaces there are some general results available under assumptions on the rank of the second fundamental form - see e.g. Vol 5 Chap 12 of Spivak's DG. [The introduction of this paper](https://publications.ias.edu/sites/default/files/someisometric.pdf) has some good discussion and references, including an older result that gives rigidity for generic metrics if the codimension is low enough.

Answer (score 3):

This certainly isn't true in general.  For instance, if $M=\mathbb{R}$, then any smooth injective curve parametrized by arc length is an isometric embedding, but such curves certainly aren't all conjugate up to ambient isometry (if $n>1$).  Or if $M$ is disconnected, you can't expect a single ambient isometry to be able to simultaneously do what you want on each of its components.  I don't know whether there are any reasonable conditions under which embeddings are unique up to ambient isometry.